# Is there any logic to use group by with aggregate and cases?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Refer below for source data :

```
|Id  |  Value 
| C1 |  0.76
| C1 |  <0.65
| C1 |  <0.35
| C2 |  0.27
| C2 |  3.7 
| C3 |  <2.5
| C3 |  <3.6
```

I have to transform this , with a condition that :

1. If all value for certain id is starting with this "<" , append into a single string
2. if all the values are numeric, average them.
3. if any value for certain id is starting with this "<"  append it

**Expected Output :**

```
|Id  |  Value 
| C1 |  0.76,<0.65,<0.35
| C2 |  1.985
| C3 |  <2.5,<3.6
```

I have tried aggregating it with query, but not able to average it using case

**Used query :**

```
Select id,
case when value like '%<%' then listagg(value,',')
     else avg(cast(value as decimal(38,10))) 
 end as Value
from table
```

Issue is two things,

1. not able to average the numerical values
2. how to handle one numerical and one string value here to append

Comment: I think the main issue here is that your rules are sort of exclusive in nature, the way they're written. Instead, you might want to try to rewrite the rules, such as this: If any values in the group does not start with '<', average them, and this becomes the value of the group. If no such values exists, then the group value starts out empty. Then, secondly, concatenate onto the first value (average or blank) any remainding values starting with '<'.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a value of `'a'`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment, but if you will check my query , I am almost doing the same thing i.e if any value is  starting with '<', append else average

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using / which DBMS are you using? (MySQL has different functionality to SQL Server, which is different to Oracle, which is different to PostgreSQL, etc, etc.)

Comment: There won't be any value like 'a', ther

Comment: Perhaps a UNION ALL, with one SELECT for the listagg ID's, and another one for the AVG ID's.

Comment: @MatBailie using PostgreSQL

Comment: Tried one more thing here, 

SQL : Select Id, case when value like '%<%' then 0 else 1 end as average_it from table,

but again I need this flag to be applicable on Id group , not to a particular id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points...

You're trying to use functions that don't exist in PostgreSQL. So, I've swapped them to PostgreSQL functions.

You need to safely convert strings to numbers (else the `'<'` will cause errors).

You can't check a scalar value (from before GROUP BY / aggregation) in a CASE expression, then return an aggregate. You need to check a scalar and return a scalar or check an aggregate and return an aggregate. (The following does the latter.)

A column can't contain strings ***and*** numeric values, so the numerics must be converted back to strings.

```
WITH
  safe_agg AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    STRING_AGG(value, ',')           AS string_list,
    AVG(TO_NUMBER(value, '999.999')) AS number_avg
  FROM
    table
  GROUP BY
    id
)
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN string_list LIKE '%<%'
    THEN string_list
    ELSE number_avg::TEXT
  END
FROM
  safe_agg
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/y5DakXm6

Comment: This is not a complete answer and is erroring out. Can you please recheck and provide a complete and executable answer?

Comment: @Madhukar It seems to work on a fiddle... https://dbfiddle.uk/y5DakXm6 What particularly is incomplete? And what error do you get?

Comment: In fiddle, it is working fine. I said the code is incomplete because values are missing inside cte.

Comment: @Madhukar A correct answer refers to the ***table*** the data is in, not a cte

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie working fine for me, also using string_agg was giving error in my case so used listagg

Comment: @HarshShukla then you're ***not*** using postgresql.

Comment: @MatBailie checked configuration using 

SELECT * FROM information_schema.sql_implementation_info;

It's showing postgreSQL only

Comment: @HarshShukla Is this a standard distribution, or some kind of custom, managed PostgreSQL distribution, possibly from a cloud provider? In a standard version [there's no `listagg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) and there never was unless you defined one yourself or had someone add it in. There's one [in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html). What error did you get for `string_agg()`? What is `select version();` showing?

Comment: Version is PostgreSQL 8.0.2 ,Redshift (RDBMS) and yes listagg() is a custom function here, the error that i am getting for string_agg is :  function string_agg does not exist , no function matches the given name and argument type

Comment: Redshift is based on postgresql but is actually so far removed that it has its own tag here.

Comment: ok, Thanks, I was not sure about that, will keep in mind before asking here

Answer (score 1):

If you're in mood for exercise, you can combine [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) with aggregate [`filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jh93nTvj)

```sql
select id,
       coalesce( substring(string_agg(value,',') from '.*<.*'),
                 avg(value::decimal(38,10))filter(where not value~'.*<.*')::text
               ) as value
from test
group by id;
```

[`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) nullifies the string if it doesn't have a `<` in it, in which case it falls back on the `avg()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in both `postgresql` and `SQL Server` which gives the expected output.

**Postgresql**

```
WITH temp1 (id, value) 
AS (VALUES 
('c1','0.76'),
('c1','<0.65'),
('c1','<0.35'),
('c2','0.27'),
('c2','3.7'),
('c3','<2.5'),
('c3','<3.6'))
,temp2 AS (
  SELECT id, 
    STRING_AGG(value, ',') list,
    AVG(TO_NUMBER(value, 'S9999D99')) avg
  FROM temp1
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN list LIKE '%<%' THEN list ELSE avg::TEXT END
FROM temp2 
ORDER BY id
```

**SQL Server**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp (id VARCHAR(2), value VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c1','0.76'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c1','<0.65'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c1','<0.35'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c2','0.27'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c2','3.7'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c3','<2.5'
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'c3','<3.6'

;
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT id, 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST([Value] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE (ID = res.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Value,
    AVG(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,value)) avg
  FROM #temp res
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN Value LIKE '%<%' THEN Value ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,avg) END
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: That looks a lot like SQL Server, but the op said postgresql

Comment: @MatBailie - Oh I think op tagged postgresql later.  I will edit the answer

Comment: I asked, you assumed

Comment: You asked, I answered in both versions. Appreciate your concern!

Comment: This is not a complete answer and is erroring out. Can you please recheck and provide a complete and executable answer? *(I'm being sarcastic, just pointing out that your SQL Server answer references a temp table, which doesn't get created in your code, and that in fact that's completely fine.)*

Comment: That's great, thanks for all the efforts

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it: use two different queries, one for records with numbers and the other for rows with `<`, then merge them using a `UNION ALL`.

```
with cte as (
  Select id
  from mytable
  group by id
  having count(*) = sum(case when value like '<%' then 0 else 1 end)
)
select t.id, avg(value::decimal)::varchar as Value
from mytable t
where t.id in (select id from cte)
group by t.id
union all
select t.id, STRING_AGG(value,',')
from mytable t
where t.id not in (select id from cte)
group by t.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fiycIqlu)